# Moving Div to the right of a column and under another column

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, view, grid

I am pretty new to HTML/CSS. I would like the div (on the bottom of the markup below) that contains the `<p> posts </p>` to fall to the right of the `<div class="small-3 columns">` and underneath the `<div class="small-9 columns">`. How can I accomplish this? Everything I've tried is not working..

```
  <div class="small-3 columns">
    <%= image_tag @user.image_url(:thumb) %><br>
    <h3> <%= @user.first_name %> <%=@user.last_name %> </h3><br>
    <h4>Personal Info</h4>
      <strong>Email:</strong><br> <%= @user.email %><br>
      <% unless @user.date_of_birth.blank? %>
        <strong>Date of Birth:</strong><br> <%= @user.date_of_birth %>
      <% end %> <br>
      <% unless @user.home_town.blank? %>
        <strong>Home Town:</strong><br> <%= @user.home_town %>
      <% end %> <br>
      <% unless @user.current_location.blank? %>
        <strong>Current Location:</strong><br> <%= @user.current_location %>
      <% end %><br>
      <% unless @user.about_me.blank? %>
        <strong>About Me:</strong><br> <%= @user.about_me %>
      <% end %><br>
  </div>
  <div class="small-9 small-centered columns">
    <div>
      <ul class="left">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" data-reveal-id="activitiesModal"><h3>Favorite Activities</h3></a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" data-reveal-id="eventsModal"><h3>Events I'm Attending</h3></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="activitiesModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
      <h4>Stuff I Like</h4>
      <ul class="panel callout">
        <% @user.activities.each do |activity| %>
          <li><%= activity.name %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
      <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>
    <div id="eventsModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
      <h4> Events I'm Attending </h4>
      <% @user.events.each do |event| %>
        <ul class="panel callout radius">
          <li>Event: <%= event.activity.name %></li>
          <li>Start Time: <%= event.start_time.to_s(:format_time) %></li>
          <li>Location: <%= event.location_name %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'View Details', user_event_path(current_user, event) %></li>
        </ul>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p> posts </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `small-offset-3` class from Foundation to achieve this.

The part that has 'posts' in it would be changed to this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-9 small-offset-3 columns">
    <p>posts</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will now be the same width as the previous `small-9` div but will have an offset of 3 columns.

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/UnoMIPa/1/edit)**

---

**EDIT**

To have the 'posts' content as part of the first `small-9` column, you can either just add the `<p>posts</p>` after the closing `</div>` of `<div id="events-modal>` or you can nest a row inside `<div class="small-9 columns">`.

```
<div class="small-9 columns">
  ...
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12">
      <p>posts</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that your class of `small-centered` is causing the layout to break because you're not overriding that centered on larger devices.  I've removed it.

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/UnoMIPa/2/edit)**

Comment: thanks for your help. Is there a way to get it to fall directly underneath the small-9 column content? It appears below it but at the bottom of the page below where the small-3 columns content ends. I'm pretty much looking for the small-3 column content to be fixed and for everything else to fall under the small-9 columns

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for the tips that was really helpful. All is laid out properly now as well.

Comment: Good stuff, glad to help.  Could you mark as correct if you're happy with the answer?